# MYSQL - Query to check against other table (hard to explain...)

Tags: sql, mysql, select

I have a query that gets a list of emails who have subscribed for a newsletter trial which lasts 30 days..

```
$thirty = time() - 3024000;

SELECT c.email 
  FROM tbl_clients AS c 
  JOIN tbl_clientoptions AS o ON o.client = c.id 
 WHERE o.option = 'newsletter' 
   AND c.datecreated > $thirty
```

What I want to do is do a check in that same query so it also returns clients OVER 30 days old if they have the tbl_clientoptions.option = 'trialoverride' (ie; a row in the client options table with the value "trialoverride")

`TBL_CLIENTS` table:

- id
- name
- email
- datecreated

`TBL_CLIENTOPTIONS` table:

- id
- client
- option

Comment: Sounds like you want to `UNION` two select statements together, the second one with a join to TBL_CLIENTOPTIONS

Comment: the options table has things like newsletter,promotionalmaterial,smsalerts, monthlynewsletter, etc and also has an option for trialoverride.
There are multiple rows depending on what options are ticked. If there is a client with newsletter and sms alerts, there will be two rows. If we untick something, a row is deleted.

What I want to do is select all who have 'newsletter' ticked and are less than 30 days old, and all the people who have 'newsletter' ticked that are older than 30 days if they have 'trial override' ticked.

I can probably do two queries, but was hoping to do in one..

Answer (score 0):

How about:

```
SELECT c.email 
   FROM tbl_clients AS c JOIN tbl_clientoptions AS o
   ON o.client = c.id 
   WHERE (o.option = 'newsletter' AND c.datecreated > $thirty) 
     || o.option = 'trialoverride';
```

Comment: I think I tried this, but it conflicts with the other 'option' column (ie: the row cant equal 'newsletter' and 'trialoverride' at the same time) Is this right?

Comment: Sorry, didn't see that. I've edited it to what I think should work instead. Basically, moved the ()s around a little.

Answer (score 0):

Normally just a `OR` condition will do it, added a `DISTINCT` if a same user user can have both condition, otherwise remove it :

```
SELECT DISTINCT c.email 
FROM tbl_clients c 
 INNER JOIN tbl_clientoptions o ON (o.client = c.id) 
WHERE
 (o.option = 'newsletter' AND c.datecreated < $thirty) OR
 (o.option = 'trial override' AND c.datecreated > $thirty);
```